# Как вызвать событие в content.js при взаимодействии с popup.html в расширении chrome

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension

При клике на кнопку в popup.html данного рассширения надо показать или скрыть блок на странице. Но как передать это событие в content.js. Пожалуйста разъясните как создать эту связь. Спасибо !